# MVC C# Count Records Based on Condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am trying to count and display the number of logs conducted by various users from the Admin section.
Each user has a  UserID and through this, I would like to count and display data from a specific table.
I have made of a stored procedure and passed it to the Controller via a ViewBag but it keeps returning 1 as the total for all values.
 the procedure is Below

```
CREATE proc [Usp_GetCallCountByUserID]
@UserID int output
AS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Customer Where UserID= @UserID
GROUP BY UserID
set @UserID =@@ROWCOUNT
END
GO
```

Controller:

```
     public ActionResult Index()
       {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Usp_GetCallCountByUserID", con);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction =
            ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Close();
        ViewBag.CountLog = comm.Parameters["@UserID"].Value.ToString();
        con.Close();

        var callCustomers = db.Registrations;
        return View(callCustomers.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: alternatively what is the best way to work around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: answer edited after clarification**

If I'm right you would do something like this:

```
CREATE proc [Usp_GetCallCountByUserID]
  @UserId int
  @TotalCount int output
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE UserId = @UserId
END
```

Please modify calling c# code accordingly. You do not need the GROUP BY clause, if grouping by the same field you are filtering on.

Consideration: IMO a stored procedure is overkill for such a simple task, and does not give any sensible performance improvements, expecially if your application and DB server are always up (both will optimize the query execution, if repeated). When queries are so simple, I'd rather execute a CommandType.Text DbCommand:

```
conn.Open();
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Customer where UserId = @UserId";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = currentUserId;
   using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      reader.Read(); // Advance one record
      ViewBag.CountLog = reader.GetInt32(0);
   }
}
```

Finally, since you seem to be using some sort of ORM (Entity Framework?), why not just:

```
db.Customers.Count(c => c.UserId == currentUserId);
```

That is pretty much equivalent to the code above.

Comment: Yes this code would work for me if i wanted to retrieve total records. But what i really want is a query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers WHERE UserID=@UserID. This is because i have various userids and thus need for each user

Comment: Oh, ok, you have Customers that have a foreign key to Users. One User can have one or more Customer. You want to find total Customers count for the current User. If this is correct, I'll modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Exactly. I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

First of all your stored procedure does exactly as expected, since `@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows in the result.

You have to write your result in another variable like shown below.

**For your Stored Procedure**

```
DECLARE @Result INT
SELECT  @Result = COUNT (*) FROM Customer Where UserID= @UserID
GROUP BY UserID
```

And then Read this value ;)

**And Changes for your Code**

```
reader.Close();
ViewBag.CountLog = comm.Parameters["@Result"].Value.ToString();
con.Close();
```

Comment: The formal parameter "@UserID" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.'

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variable @@ROWCOUNT

you have to save the value of COUNT(*) in your request, look code below,

```
CREATE proc [Usp_GetCallCountByUserID]
    @UserID int,
    @RowCount int output 
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT @RowCount = COUNT (*) FROM Customer Where UserID= @UserID
    GROUP BY UserID
    END
    GO
```